# IndexError: too many indices for array when changing to BGR

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to load an image, but I'm encountering the following error:

> im = im[:, :, ::-1]  # change to BGR IndexError: too many indices for
>   array

I read the image file by :

```
....
....
im = np.asarray(Image.open(
        osp.join(self.data_root, image_file_name)))
    im = scipy.misc.imresize(im, self.im_shape)  # resize
    return self.transformer.preprocess(im)
```

And here is the function that yelds the error:

```
def preprocess(self, im):
    im = np.float32(im)
    im = im[:, :, ::-1]  # change to BGR
    im -= self.mean
    im *= self.scale
    im = im.transpose((2, 0, 1))
    return im
```

I don't understand what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the image is RGB? I suspect that the image is actually grayscale, so it's a 2d array. What is `im.shape`?

Comment: Nevermind, you're manually reshaping to `self.im_shape`. So what is `self.im_shape`? I suspect it's a 2-element sequence.

Comment: Hi, self.im_shape
[227, 227]

Comment: So you should check `im.shape` *after* calling `imresize` on it. The result is probably a 2d array, in which case you should pass `[227,227,3]` as `self.im_shape` (although I'm guessing). Also, side note: `im=im.astype(np.float32)` is probably more idiomatic.